# Angle brackets on Swedish Apple Magic Keyboard connected to Windows laptop

Tags: windows-10, mac, keyboard

I just upgraded my old Apple USB keyboard to an Apple Magic Keyboard (both with the Swedish keyboard layout). Now I'm not able to type angle brackets (less/greater than signs). This was not a problem with the old keyboard. When pressing the angle brackets key the output is "§" and "½" instead. Any ideas on how can I fix that?